# Clang-16 compiler segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, clang, ninja

I am compiling my project with clang-16 which worked fine so far, but now I am getting a segmentation fault from clang itself during compilation:

```
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/ccache /usr/bin/clang++ -DHAVE_CBLAS=1 -DSPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL=SPDLOG_LEVEL_DEBUG -DSPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL -DXTENSOR_USE_XSIMD -I/tmp/reinforce/src/libreinforce/include -I/tmp/reinforce/test/shared_test_utils -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/pcg-c4aa2cafcf36e3/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/range0301bf3d76d5d/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/fmted8c40f5dd02d/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/xtens8c3f32033d144/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/xtl7161fe009dc21/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/nlohm0567ffc90cfc1/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/xsimd7b0628df207bb/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/spdlo0e2ce77e2e884/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/froze7ac551bf2fb61/p/include -isystem /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/_deps/xtensor-python-src/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/pybin895b9560d7d3f/p/include -isystem /usr/include/python3.10 -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -isystem /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/_deps/xtensor-blas-src/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/gtest79f180a2a4833/p/include -g -std=gnu++20 -fcolor-diagnostics -g3 -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 -flto -funroll-loops -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wold-style-cast -Wcast-align -Wunused -Woverloaded-virtual -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat=2 -Winvalid-pch -Xclang -include-pch -Xclang /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.pch -Xclang -include -Xclang /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp.o -c /tmp/reinforce/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp
Segmentation fault
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

There is no stacktrace or any other further info on where or how this happens so I am a little lost. Compiling with -v (verbose mode) doesn't add any further info except for the exact run command

```
Run Build Command(s): /usr/bin/ninja -v reinforce_tests_all
[1/2] /usr/bin/ccache /usr/bin/clang++ -DHAVE_CBLAS=1 -DSPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL=SPDLOG_LEVEL_DEBUG -DSPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL -DXTENSOR_USE_XSIMD -I/tmp/reinforce/src/libreinforce/include -I/tmp/reinforce/test/shared_test_utils -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/pcg-c4aa2cafcf36e3/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/range0301bf3d76d5d/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/fmted8c40f5dd02d/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/xtens8c3f32033d144/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/xtl7161fe009dc21/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/nlohm0567ffc90cfc1/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/xsimd7b0628df207bb/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/spdlo0e2ce77e2e884/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/froze7ac551bf2fb61/p/include -isystem /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/_deps/xtensor-python-src/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/pybin895b9560d7d3f/p/include -isystem /usr/include/python3.10 -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -isystem /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/_deps/xtensor-blas-src/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/gtest79f180a2a4833/p/include -g -std=gnu++20 -fcolor-diagnostics -g3 -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 -flto -funroll-loops -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wold-style-cast -Wcast-align -Wunused -Woverloaded-virtual -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat=2 -Winvalid-pch -Xclang -include-pch -Xclang /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.pch -Xclang -include -Xclang /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp.o -c /tmp/reinforce/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp
FAILED: CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp.o
/usr/bin/ccache /usr/bin/clang++ -DHAVE_CBLAS=1 -DSPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL=SPDLOG_LEVEL_DEBUG -DSPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL -DXTENSOR_USE_XSIMD -I/tmp/reinforce/src/libreinforce/include -I/tmp/reinforce/test/shared_test_utils -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/pcg-c4aa2cafcf36e3/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/range0301bf3d76d5d/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/fmted8c40f5dd02d/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/xtens8c3f32033d144/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/xtl7161fe009dc21/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/nlohm0567ffc90cfc1/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/xsimd7b0628df207bb/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/spdlo0e2ce77e2e884/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/froze7ac551bf2fb61/p/include -isystem /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/_deps/xtensor-python-src/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/pybin895b9560d7d3f/p/include -isystem /usr/include/python3.10 -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -isystem /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/_deps/xtensor-blas-src/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/gtest79f180a2a4833/p/include -g -std=gnu++20 -fcolor-diagnostics -g3 -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 -flto -funroll-loops -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wold-style-cast -Wcast-align -Wunused -Woverloaded-virtual -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat=2 -Winvalid-pch -Xclang -include-pch -Xclang /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.pch -Xclang -include -Xclang /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp.o -c /tmp/reinforce/test/libreinforce/test_space_tuple.cpp
Segmentation fault
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I would expect clang to throw the stacktrace or other info on this, so I am actually unsure if this is even clang's or potentially ninja's segfault?

Comment: What is the difference in *your* code between it working and it now not working? What is the difference in your systems and programs and installations?

Comment: You can look at `dmesg` what crashed. [Maybe ccache](https://github.com/ccache/ccache/discussions/1102), what version do you have?

Comment: I added a delegating template constructor to a class for a simpler API. I could probably pinpoint the code for which it occurred, but this seems like a tools problem, not a code one.

@teapot418: Thanks for the tip but I am inside a docker container so `dmesg` isn't allowed it seems (`dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted`) 
I am having `ccache version 4.5.1` and `ninja version 1.10.1`

Comment: Please do check the according bug trackers and file one yourself incase there isn't one yet.

Comment: This could be anything from bad hardware in your computer, or the code you're trying to compile is triggering a compiler bug.

Comment: Does building without ccache show the same issue? If you run the clang command directly does it still crash? You could try running the command under a debugger